# gson field with same name but different type ie Object and Array

Tags: json, gson, android

I want to parse a json like below using GSON.Please guide how to achieve this using GSON as the student field is used as a object as well as array,how should i define my pojo and how to parse this type of json.

```
{
  "school": [
    {
      "student": {
        "name": "Rose", 
        "address": "some address"
      }, 
      "age": "15", 
      "section": "A"
    }, 
    {
      "student": [
        {
          "name": "David", 
          "address": "Some place"
        }
      ], 
      "age": "14", 
      "section": "B"
    }
  ]
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("school");
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<School>>(){}.getType();
listSchool = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);
```

> getting com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT exception

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate POJO java classes with this service: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

For your json it generates:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.School.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class School {

@SerializedName("school")
@Expose
public List<School_> school = new ArrayList<School_>();

}
-----------------------------------com.example.School_.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class School_ {

@SerializedName("student")
@Expose
public List<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
public String age;
@SerializedName("section")
@Expose
public String section;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Student.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Student {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
public String name;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
public String address;
```

Basically you should use different class names for Student items in array and for student object.

Comment: Pojo i have created, But while parsing i am getting error com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT                                             Gson gson = new Gson();
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("school");
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<School>>(){}.getType();
            listSchool = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();JSONArray                                                     jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("school");
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<School>>(){}.getType();
 listSchool = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);